# Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection() returns only created_at & updated_at attributes

Tags: magento-1.8

If I use following, only `weight` and `status` are added.

```
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect("*");
```

If I could get `SKU` or `entity_id`, I can still make another call to get some other attributes, but that is not the option.

Answer (score 1):

The collection loads at least everything in `catalog_product_entity`, which is:

- `entity_id`
- `entity_type_id`
- `attribute_set_id`
- `type_id`
- `sku`
- `has_options`
- `required_options`
- `created_at`
- `updated_at`

If they are not loaded, something is wrong.

1. Did you try without the `addAttributeToSelect()` ?
2. Are the attributes you expect in the attribute set of the products?
3. What does the query look like? try with `$collection->load(true);`

Comment: Thank you for the response, Fabian.

1. I tried to do addAttributeToSelect('*'), but only 'weight' & 'status' get added.
2. Yes. At least price & SKU have to be if nothing else & I can do with these many.
3. The query is 'SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`'

Comment: Also, thanks for formatting my question. Will be careful in future.